# Real time opacity mask

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls, opacity

I have an collection of images that I am painting on a canvas control. I want to be able to mask and unmask parts of the canvas in real-time.

I was thinking of using a WritableBitmap for the source of the opacity mask, but WritableBitmaps are limited to drawing with a 1-pixel brush (cant change the stroke thickness).

I am able to paint on another canvas the desired opacity mask, however I would have to constantly render that canvas to an imagesource, which is super slow.

There must be a simple way.

Edit - Some details of my app:
I am creating a painting app. I draw a collection of images onto a canvas. I have a collection of these canvases (to simulate a layer system), each with their own collection of images. So I am trying to implement a feature to edit the opacity mask of each canvas (each layer) on the fly.

Here is the collection of collections code behind

```
<!--Outer collection-->
<ItemsControl Name="canvasDataBinding"
            Focusable="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="512"
            Width="512" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            ClipToBounds="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
                MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter"
                MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave"
                MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
                MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
                Background="Transparent">
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!--nested collection-->
            <ItemsControl Height="512" Width="512" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSource}" OpacityMask="{Binding Mask}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent"  
                                Height="512" 
                                Width="512" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                                    <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding CenterY}" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: by real time do you mean like 25-30 fps? or even more? appreciated if you can also share some code.

Comment: @pushpraj Just enough so that the user does not have to wait after every brush stroke for the opacity mask to be updated. 25-30 fps should be more than enough I believe.

Perhaps there is some other way instead of using the built in OpacityMask property. I created my own masking hlsl shader that takes a black and white image as the opacity mask, but I don't know how I can use for my purposes.